# Insert javascript into echo PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio

I am trying to call some audio files into my script and I want to show only a button with the option play, not the full controller html5 of audio.

```
    for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
           echo "<div class='slide bit" . $i . " rest-slide images-slides'>";
                 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                 echo "<div class='row'>";
                    printf ("%s \n", $row["name"]);
                 echo "</div>";
                 echo "<div class='row'>";
                    echo "<img src='media/bits/" . $row["file"] . "'>";
                 echo "</div>";
                 echo "<div class='row'>";
                    echo "<audio id='player' src='media/audios/"  . $row["audio"] .  "'></audio>";
                    echo "<button onclick='document.getElementById('player').play();'>Reproducir</button>";
                 echo "</div>";
           echo "</div>";
}
```

On the web the code is like this and i cant listen de audio,

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById(" player').play();'="">Reproducir</button>
```

Any advice?

Thanks for all.

SOLVED by @lex82

The code now is like this and it works fine,

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
           echo "<div class='slide bit" . $i . " rest-slide images-slides'>";
                 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                 echo "<div class='row'>";
                    printf ("%s \n", $row["name"]);
                 echo "</div>";
                 echo "<div class='row'>";
                    echo "<img src='media/bits/" . $row["file"] . "'>";
                 echo "</div>";
                 echo "<div class='row'>";
                    $id = $row["name"];
                    echo "<audio id=". $id . " src='media/audios/"  . $row["audio"] .  "'></audio>";
                    echo "<button onclick=\"document.getElementById('". $id . "').play()\">Reproducir</button>";
                 echo "</div>";
           echo "</div>";
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the quotes like this:

```
echo "<button onclick=\"document.getElementById('player').play()\">Reproducir</button>";
```

Comment: Thanks @lex82, now I can listen the audio, but no the others, I have ten files to listen but only works the first of the array.

Comment: you are using the same id "player" ten times. You should add the index to the id.

Comment: Thanks, you have help so much @lex82, i have indexed the id player and it works fine.